# android sax xml parsing with multiple parent

Tags: java, xml, data-binding

I am trying to parse data from a xml page through sax parsing technique.The structure of the xml page is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<news_magazine>
    <latest_news>
        <news>
            <category_id>5</category_id>
            <author>Super Admin</author>
        </news>
        <news>
            <category_id>6</category_id>
            <author>user</author>
        </news>
    </latest_news>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <category_id>5</category_id>
            <category_name>cricket</category_name>
        </category>
        <category>
            <category_id>5</category_id>
            <category_name>cricket</category_name>
        </category>
    </categories>
</news_magazine>
```

Both the news tag and category tag contains category id.How can i take the the category id separately?

Comment: Looks like XML is not proper one. Please update proper XML.

Comment: Consider using an XML-to-object mapping? Constructing parsers by hand is tedious and error prone, try something like .. eh.. [pulloid](http://code.google.com/p/pulloid/) for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do this in very simple way. Just maintain a extra variable
when you put conditions in the parser when you get any of "news" or "category" tag than assign that in current_parent.
and when comparing the tag "category_id" than also put condition of current_parent

```
public static String current_parent;
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, 
            String qName, Attributes atts) {
    if (localName.equals("news") {
          current_parent = "news";
        // Do your code with news.
        return;
    }
    else  if (localName.equals("category") {
          current_parent = "category";
        // Do your code with category.
        return;
    }
     else  if (localName.equals("category_id") {
         if(current_parent.equals("category")
            {
        // Do your code with category's category_id.
             }else if(current_parent.equals("news")
               {
        // Do your code with news's category_id.
             }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use databinding of your choice and pull parser.  This task will be no-brainer with (say) xstream or jackson. IN case you really like to do it manually,  use pull parser
( you no longer receive callbacks,  but actively pull elements )  - this adapts better to java programm flow